# WKWebView "shrinking" Vimeo video being loaded

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am loading a Vimeo url with a specific video on a WKWebView, however, the video is being shrunk to a size that is undesirable. Notice the difference in the following picture between the webview (red) and the video (blue).

[image]

I made sure that:

1) The web view is **under** the transparent navigation bar

2) The web view's content mode is Aspect Fill

3) The view controller has "Adjust Scroll View Insets" set to false.

But I still can't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Its that a iFrame?

Comment: Shouldn't be.. I'm loading the direct link, in this case: https://player.vimeo.com/video/173760776

Comment: use `layer.border.width` and `layer.border.color` to see where is the real boder of your WKWebview

Comment: Its that red square.. Already checked. I sort of fixed it by setting its aspect ratio exactly at 16:9, but there's still a couple of things that look weird on iPhone X for example.